# Python TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, datetime

I've a query inside python script which connects to the sql database and retrieves a (datetime, Id) pair for that respective row. I need to iterate through the result set and filter out the 'datetime' and 'Id' part separately.
My intention is to get 'Id' for each row. So in the following query I need to filter out "275" (see below)

On writing this script:

```
cursor2.execute(query2, [item[0]])
values = cursor2.fetchone() 
#values now equals = (datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 22, 17, 17, 36), 275)
print(values[0][1])
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable

I have tried converting values to a list/string objects but nothing has been working so far. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to get by using `values[0][0]` ?

Comment: Hi just updated the question. So I need the the "Id" part for each row that I'm getting in the resultset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are simply trying to get the complete `datetime` object, then simply use `values[0]` , instead of `values[0][0]` . And for `Id` use `values[1]` . Example -

```
>>> values = (datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 22, 17, 17, 36), 275)
>>> print(values[1])
275
```

`values[0]` refers to the `datetime` object , so when you do `values[0][1]` , you are trying to use subscript on the datetime object, which is not possible, and hence the error.

This is because you are using `cursor.fetchone()` , which only returns you a single row as a tuple. If you were instead using `.fetchall()` or `.fetchmany()` , then what you get would be a list of tuples and in that case as well, you can iterate over the list , taking one tuple at a time, and getting the element at index `1`. Example -

```
for dateobj, id in cursor.fetchall():
    #Do your logic with `id`.
```

Answer (score 1):

when you call `.fetchone()` you get back a tuple (one record):

```
mydate, myid = cursor.fetchone()
```

if you just want to get the `id` for each row you could do:

```
ids = [record[1] for record in cursor.fetchall()]
```

generally, it's better to only select the data you need though, maybe:

```
cursor.execute("select id from ({subquery}) t".format(subquery=query2), [item[0]])   # assuming the id column is named id
ids = [record[0] for record in cursor.fetchall()]  # now we're only retrieving one column (index zero)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get 275, you just need

```
print(values[1])
```

assuming

```
values == (datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 22, 17, 17, 36), 275)
```